# Difference between Email Subject line and pre-header

Tags: html, email, content-management-system, html-email

Can anyone explain the difference between `html` Email **pre-header** & **subject line**, and how to include them in the code along with a picture showing how they look after sending the Email (just to get an idea), and is there a max character count for each. 
I've been looking and reading around but haven't found the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subjectline is the normal first text you see in the inbox, preheader is the 2nd test. [image]

Regarding code:  the subjectline is oftens set in the mail system it self, and the preheader is made with code.. The preheader is just the first String of text the mail client can find. So if you add this code right after the `<body>` tag

```
<div style="display:none !important">This is the preheader</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Subject line is what you see in the Inbox of every email client to describe the intent of an individual email.

Some email clients will let you preview a section of the email. This is called a preview. Since most html  marketing emails have the first line of "View on web", some marketers found they could create a section of email to be the first line that is read by email clients and call that the preview. It's generally hidden by default and allows you to summarize the email.

Different email clients will preview as little as the first 35 characters with Outlook or the first 197 characters as with Apple Mail.

Stack Overflow is happy to help answer questions about technology. It is expected that you post code to show what your issue is. There's plenty of examples out there showing how to do preview text. This isn't a dog and pony show. We don't fix your problems.